# subclassing and property assignment

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a class:

```
@interface BasicDescription : NSObject

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *author;
@property (assign,nonatomic) NSInteger year;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *owner;
```

And second class:

```
@interface AdvDescModel : BasicDescription

-(id)initWithBasicModel:(BasicDescription*)basicModel;
```

So my question is how to assign all properties when i'm create new object. Now i have

```
AdvDescModel *adv = [AdvDescModel alloc] initWithBasicModel:basic];
```

And then in initializer:

```
-(id)initWithBasicModel:(BasicDescription*)basicModel {

    if(self = [super init]) {
        [self setAllParams:basicModel];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setAllParams:(BasicDescription*)bModel {

    [self setAuthor:bModel.author];
    [self setYear:bModel.year];
    [self setOwner:bModel.owner];
}
```

But there is no better way to do this? Now i have to watch all my properties and calling setter for every one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you initialize your object is not bad, if it fullfil your requirements you can leave in this way ... However take a look at the [Builder Pattern](http://erik.doernenburg.com/2011/11/builder-pattern-in-objective-c/) that would be the best bet in these kind of situations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have many such properties, a better way to do it is to use a mutable dictionary with all the default values, and simply set that on each new object. Then you can modify values that the subclass or the user wants to change.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much better practice to have a class responsible for its own properties, so I would suggest that the `AdvDescModel` have an initializer such as...

```
-(id)initWithBasicModel:(BasicDescription*)basicModel {

    if(self = [super initWithBasicModel:basicModel]) {
        ;  // Anything specific to the subclass
    }
    return self;
}
```

...and the parent have:

```
-(id)initWithBasicModel:(BasicDescription*)bModel {

    if(self = [super init]) {
        [self setAuthor:bModel.author];
        [self setYear:bModel.year];
        [self setOwner:bModel.owner];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a "ready" BasicDescription object to initialize a new allocated one!!!

Comment: It's not a question of **needing** one but rather of accommodating the original situation which specified that one existed.  There's no requirement of only having one initializer in a class.

Comment: Of course you can have more than one initializer. But I'd rather use a helper method (not one that starts with init) to set the propertys from a BasicDescription object.

Comment: I have to admit that it's a solution I would never use. But it's also stupid from my part to consider it as inappropriate just because I wouldn't use it. (Sorry for the down vote!)

Comment: I probably developed the habit from my C++ background where copy constructors and chained constructors are both quite common.  For that matter, anyone who used `NSString` as a sample of how to implement a class might come up with the same strategy.  :)